# Functionalities don't work when using JSON + AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having trouble with working with `AJAX` + `JSON`, every time I try to dynamically write something on my web page, other functionalities just stop working...

Here is my `JS` code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "data/faq.json",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(faq){
            ispisFAQ(faq);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
    
    
    function ispisFAQ(faq){
        let ispis = '<div class="row faqRow">';

        faq.forEach(element => {
            ispis += `
            <button class="${element.class}"> ${element.question} </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    ${element.answer}
                </p>
            </div>`;
        });
        ispis += '</div>';
        document.getElementById("faqContainer").innerHTML = ispis;
    }
  }
```

And here is `JSON` file :

```js
[
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion",
        "question": "1. Do you have a store?",
        "answer": "Yes, I do! Currently I have one store on 2424 George Street in Toronto. You can see all the pieces and more there in person!"
    },
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion",
        "question": "2. Do you ship internationally?",
        "answer": "Unfortunately, no. I only ship to Canada, but I'm working on expanding!"
    },
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion", 
        "question": "3. What is your return policy?",
        "answer": "Your complete satisfaction is my number one concern.If you are not completely satisfied with your selection, you can return it within 30 days."
    },
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion",
        "question": "4. What is your jewelry made of?",
        "answer": "Quality is very important to me. So I make sure that every piece is made of Gold plated .925 sterling silver. I guarantee that it will last you a long time, with no damage."
    },
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion",
        "question": "5. Do you clean/repair jewelry?",
        "answer": "If it's one of my pieces, sure! Just contact me with details." 
    },
    {
        "class": "collapsableQuestion",
        "question": "6. Do you make any custom jewerly?",
        "answer": "It's not something I do very often, but if you like the style of my jewerly, price and quality - contact me, and I will see what I can do."
    }
]
```

But when I try to run code below, to toggle some content it won't work...

```js
var tog = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsableQuestion");

for (var i = 0; i < tog.length; i++) {
    tog[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me, when I run the same code without `AJAX` and `JSON` it works fine, what is the problem?

Comment: One question - why are you running a POST request? don't you want to run a GET request to fetch the json file?

Comment: Can you try to write code in Jquery way, for example instead of using window.onload and tog[i].addEventListener, you can use jquery $( document ).ready(function() and $.on('click', function(event)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the issue that you are having is that not all of the collapsable questions are toggling correctly. If so, as you are using jQuery, the most straightforward way to ensure that all classes toggle correctly would be like so: `function toggleAll() {
    var tog = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsableQuestion");

    for (var i = 0; i < tog.length; i++) {
        tog[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            $(this).siblings().toggleClass( "active", false);
        });
    }
}`

Comment: execute the toggleAll function like so: `$( document ).ready(function() {
  toggleAll();
});`

Comment: Yes, my problem is that it won't toggle. But, when I run my code( shown above) without ajax it works just fine... Why is ajax the problem? I have two JS files, "main.js" and "script.js" where "script.js" has javascript and jquery code in one(again, working totally fine when ajax isn't involved), and for "main.js" i wanted it to be just for ajax and functions I make for it.

Comment: @amyloula As far as I know, you can use POST and GET method, there are differences, but since this is a school project it doesn't matter which one I use. I am not sharing any sensitive or important data.

Comment: @LenkaŽivković even if it is just a school project, you should use the correct HTTP method for the correct request. If you are getting data then you should use a GET request and if you are creating data you should use POST, if you are updating data you should use PUT. https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you are forgetting to parse the json: When you receive the response to your ajax request, it's considered as text.
Here's what you should do:

```
window.onload = function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "data/faq.json",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(content){
        var data = JSON.parse(content)
        ispisFAQ(data);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

(note the JSON.parse() call)
This function converts the text you received to a javascript object you can interact with.

Cheers!

Edit:
By the way, you should check out the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It is often easier to use, and allows cleaner code

Comment: No. jQuery ajax will parse an HTTP response as JSON if (a) `dataType` is "`auto"` and the `Content-Type` says it is JSON **or** (b) `dataType` is `"json"`. Also, if the problem was that the JSON wasn't being parsed then the problem would be that *the data doesn't show up* not that the toggle functionality didn't work.

Comment: Oh, you're right... I'm actually not very used to jQuery and answered a bit too fast. sorry for that.